# Change parameters in a layer of a keras NN

Tags: python, keras

I have created a neural network in Keras like this:

```
model=Sequential()
model.add(Dense(100, input_dim=X_values.shape[1],init='uniform',activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(1))
```

is it possible to change the number of neurons from 100 to 10 in the hidden layer or change the type of activation function without creating a new model from scratch?

Comment: Can you explain more on what you're trying to do? Just expand a little on the part "without creating a new model from scratch"

Comment: I want to do some custom cross validation changing the number of the neurons in hidden layers of the network and test the accuracy of the model.

Comment: You can make changes to the model by popping out the layers; see documentation - https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-remove-a-layer-from-a-sequential-model. I am not sure if you can edit the model in between.

Comment: Even if I popped out a layer I would have to create and add a new one from scratch, so it would not make so much difference